# What's the difference between if nil != optional … and if let _ = optional …

Tags: swift, option-type

I need to test if an expression which returns an optional is `nil`. This seems like a no-brainer, but here is the code.

```
if nil != self?.checklists.itemPassingTest({ $0 === note.object }) {
    …
}
```

Which, for some reason, looks unpleasant to my eye.

```
if let item = self?.checklists.itemPassingTest({ $0 === note.object }) {
    …
}
```

Looks much better to me, but I don't actually need the item, I just need to know if one was returned. So, I used the following.

```
if let _ = self?.checklists.itemPassingTest({ $0 === note.object }) {
    …
}
```

Am I missing something subtle here? I think `if nil != optional …` and `if let _ = optional …` are equivalent here.

---

**Update to address some concerns in the answers**

1. I don't see the difference between `nil != var` and `var != nil`, although I generally use `var != nil`. In this case, pushing the `!= nil` after the block gets the boolean compare of block mixed in with the boolean compare of the if.
2. The use of the [Wildcard Pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/wildcard-pattern) should not be all that surprising or uncommon. They are used in tuples `(x, _) = (10, 20)`, for-in loops `for _ in 1...5`, case statements `case (_, 0):`, and more (NOTE: these examples were taken from The Swift Programming Language).

This question is about the functional equivalency of the two forms, not about coding style choices. That conversation can be had on programmers.stackexchange.com.

---

After all this time, Swift 2.0 makes it moot

```
if self?.checklists.contains({ $0 === note.object }) ?? false {
    …
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After optimization, the two approaches are probably the same.

For example, in this case, compiling both the following with `swiftc -O -emit-assembly if_let.swift`:

```
import Darwin

// using arc4random ensures -O doesn’t just
// ignore your if statement completely
let i: Int? = arc4random()%2 == 0 ? 2 : nil

if i != nil {
  println("set!")
}
```

vs

```
import Darwin

let i: Int? = arc4random()%2 == 0 ? 2 : nil

if let _ = i {
  println("set!")
}
```

produces identical assembly code:

```
    ; call to arc4random
    callq   _arc4random
    ; check if LSB == 1 
    testb   $1, %al
    ; if it is, skip the println
    je  LBB0_1
    movq    $0, __Tv6if_let1iGSqSi_(%rip)
    movb    $1, __Tv6if_let1iGSqSi_+8(%rip)
    jmp LBB0_3
LBB0_1:
    movq    $2, __Tv6if_let1iGSqSi_(%rip)
    movb    $0, __Tv6if_let1iGSqSi_+8(%rip)
    leaq    L___unnamed_1(%rip), %rax  ; address of "set!" literal
    movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
    movq    $4, -32(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -24(%rbp)
    movq    __TMdSS@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rsi
    addq    $8, %rsi
    leaq    -40(%rbp), %rdi
    ; call println
    callq   __TFSs7printlnU__FQ_T_
LBB0_3:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

Comment: `func check (x:Int) { /* arc4random() -> x */ } ` reduces output from 1,000 pages to 1.5. :-)

Comment: In this instance, I wasn't concerned with performance, but knowing they have equivalent binary representations reassures me.

Answer (score 19):

The `if let` syntax is called optional binding. It takes an optional as input and gives you back a required constant if the optional is not nil. This is intended for the common code pattern where you first check to see if a value is nil, and if it's not nil (if it has a value), you do something with it.

If the optional **is** nil, processing stops and the code inside the braces is skipped.

The `if optional != nil` syntax is simpler. It simply checks to see if the optional is nil. It skips creating a required constant for you.

The optional binding syntax is wasteful and confusing if you're not going to use the resulting value. Use the simpler `if optional != nil` version in that case. As nhgrif points out, it generates less code, plus your intentions are much clearer.

### EDIT:

It sounds like the compiler is smart enough to not generate extra code if you write "if let" optional binding code but don't end up using the variable you bind. The main difference is in readability. Using optional binding creates the expectation that you are going to use the optional that you bind.

Comment: Considering the [number](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) of [times](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID275) [`for _ in range`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) is used in Apple's swift examples, I don't think an unbound variable should be all that surprising.

Comment: As this poster said, and as I added above in another comment, source code is human-readable code and thus should express how a human would speak the logic.  Reading the logic out loud it's saying 'If this is not nil, then...' which translates exactly to 'if x != nil { ...' in the source, meaning that's much more readable. Honestly, I don't see the benefit at all of 'if let _ = x' over it. Perhaps it's just a byproduct of being able to pattern-match when you don't care about one or more of the values, and in order to support that, it ended up creating the 'if let _' nonsense.

Comment: `for _ in range` is a very different case. In that case you're running a loop a specific number of times, but don't need the index value.

Answer (score 5):

I personally think it looks unpleasant because you are comparing nil to your result instead of your result to nil:

```
if self?.checklists.itemPassingTest({ $0 === note.object }) != nil {
    …
}
```

Since you only want to ensure it is not nil and not use `item` there is no point in using `let`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of AirspeedVelocity show us that `let _ =` and `!= nil` produce the same assembly code, therefore I strongly suggest using the first approach.

In fact, if you have something like:

```
if let _ = optional {
    do_something()
}
```

...and you want to add some code and now you need that optional, this change will be easier and quicker:

```
if let wrapped = optional {
    do_something()
    do_something_else(with: wrapped)
}
```

Use `let _ =` and write maintainable code.

Comment: I was about to vote this up, but then I thought about what source code is... human-readable code.  While you're right that it's easier to change in the future should you need the value, it's not that hard to change from the other syntax. More importantly, until then (if ever), it's not as readable.  Think about it... reading the logic out loud it's saying 'If this is not nil, then...' which translates exactly to 'if x != nil { ...' in the source, meaning that's much more readable. That's why I had a change of heart.

Comment: I'd argue neither one is more maintainable.  Like as a counter example to yours, the code could become: `if optional == nil || optional2 == nil { print("at least one of these is nil!") }`, which would not be accomplishable as a one liner using the the `let _ =`