# What's the point of if let statements?

Tags: swift

I've read Swift docs on optional binding but it's incomprehensible to me at my level of knowledge (and/or intelligence).

What's the difference between:

```
var number:Int? = 1
if let num = number {
    print("number is \(number!)"
} else {
    print("it must be nil")
}
```

and

```
var number:Int? = 1
if number==nil {
    print("it must be nil")
} else {
    print("number is \(number!)"
}
```

As far as I can tell, these work the same, and at least to me the second one is more readable. And I wouldn't ordinarily care about something like this, but `if let` is prominent in most basic tutorials like it's something useful, so I'd really like to know why.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but [related question talking about the differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322977/whats-the-difference-between-if-nil-optional-and-if-let-optional)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you had two optional values A and B
classic syntax

```
if a != nil {
    if a?.b != nil {
        here access a.b.blah 
    }
}
```

new syntax

```
if let blah=a?.b?.blah {
   use blah ...
}
```

it's shorter,more readable and more  flexible

Comment: Ah, my lack of knowledge emerges. It's not more readable to me, but I guess I'll get it with experience.

Comment: it was weird for me too at first (coming from java), but then i realized... yay!!! no more checking for nulls

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
print("number is \(num)"
```

so what it does it does the nil check and the assignment to a non optiional constand in one line

Comment: I know what it does, but why would I need a non optional constant?

Comment: maybe you dont want to write the number! at possibly 1000 places

Comment: Yes but then my first line in the else block can be `var n = number!`. Wouldn't that be the same thing? I don't really care to nit pick but I'm afraid I'm missing / misunderstanding something.

Comment: yes but that would decrease the readability of your code. - so it is "syntax sugar"

Comment: Well the point of my questions is that it's not as readable to me. I've wasted an hour trying to understand the point of this, so I guess it's just one of those things that don't make sense to me.

Comment: well there is the point: when you have a ```if let myvar = somemethodcallthatreturnsanoptional() {...}``` thenhaving 2 extra vars for the optional and non optional would make it less readable imho

Answer (score 0):

The answer is avoid the force unwrapping in one of the clause.
The fact you always see one statement after the clause is not helpful, but imagine that you have a lot more statements in the scope where you variable is different from nil, imagine to remember the ! for each time you need to refer to the unwrapped value.
Using `if let` probably the compiler translate it in a normal check for nil and then a simple variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `if let` statement, you also get the benefit of unwrapping the optional value `number` to the non-optional `Int` within the scope of your `if let` statement.

```
var number: Int? = 1
if let number = number {
    // number is an Int
    print("number is \(number!)")
} else {
    // number is an Int?
    print("it must be nil")
}
```