# In Swift, why is "let _ = this" faster then "this != nil"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, syntactic-sugar

So my question is why is `let _ = this` faster then `this != nil`?

Example:

This is:

```
let this : Bool? = true //

let start = DispatchTime.now()
for _ in 0...100000000  {
    guard this != nil else { continue }
}
let end = DispatchTime.now()

let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime)
print("Time \(timeInterval)") 

         // Time 5426559135.0
         // Time 5428084767.0
         // Time 5327325459.0
```

Slower than:

```
let this : Bool? = true //

let start = DispatchTime.now()
for _ in 0...100000000  {
    guard let _ = this else { continue }
}
let end = DispatchTime.now()

let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime)
print("Time \(timeInterval)")

          // Time 257045414.0
          // Time 261933863.0
          // Time 263465919.0
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704317/jonathan)'s [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442197/3923929) I checked the actual disassembled instructions.
Here is the result:
For the code:

```
let this : Bool? = nil
this != nil
```

we get:

```
    0x100001290 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x100001291 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100001294 <+4>:  subq   $0x30, %rsp
    0x100001298 <+8>:  leaq   0x2c7259(%rip), %rdx      ; type metadata for Swift.Bool
    0x10000129f <+15>: leaq   0x2b66ca(%rip), %rcx      ; protocol witness table for Swift.Bool : Swift.Equatable in Swift
    0x1000012a6 <+22>: leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rax
    0x1000012aa <+26>: leaq   -0x8(%rbp), %r8
    0x1000012ae <+30>: movb   $0x2, 0x2f940b(%rip)
    0x1000012b5 <+37>: movb   0x2f9404(%rip), %r9b      ; test2.this : Swift.Optional<Swift.Bool>
    0x1000012bc <+44>: movb   %r9b, -0x8(%rbp)
    0x1000012c0 <+48>: movb   $0x2, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x1000012c4 <+52>: movb   -0x10(%rbp), %r9b
    0x1000012c8 <+56>: movb   %r9b, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x1000012cc <+60>: movl   %edi, -0x1c(%rbp)
    0x1000012cf <+63>: movq   %r8, %rdi
    0x1000012d2 <+66>: movq   %rsi, -0x28(%rbp)
    0x1000012d6 <+70>: movq   %rax, %rsi
    0x1000012d9 <+73>: callq  0x10004df10               ; Swift.!= infix <A where A: Swift.Equatable> (Swift.Optional<A>, Swift.Optional<A>) -> Swift.Bool
    0x1000012de <+78>: xorl   %r10d, %r10d
    0x1000012e1 <+81>: movb   %al, -0x29(%rbp)
    0x1000012e4 <+84>: movl   %r10d, %eax
    0x1000012e7 <+87>: addq   $0x30, %rsp
    0x1000012eb <+91>: popq   %rbp
    0x1000012ec <+92>: retq
```

and for:

```
let this : Bool? = nil
let _ = this
```

there is:

```
    0x1000012d0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x1000012d1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x1000012d4 <+4>:  xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x1000012d6 <+6>:  movb   $0x2, 0x2f93e3(%rip)
    0x1000012dd <+13>: movl   %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
    0x1000012e0 <+16>: movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x1000012e4 <+20>: popq   %rbp
    0x1000012e5 <+21>: retq
```

Also, thank you [Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different) for pointing to the *Optimisation level*.

Changing the value from **[-Onone]** to **[-O -whole-module-optimisation]** will cause a change for the generated asm in the following way:

The

```
let this : Bool? = nil
let _ = this
```

has

```
    0x100001490 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x100001491 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100001494 <+4>:  movb   $0x2, 0x3d9595(%rip)      ; gCRAnnotations + 63
    0x10000149b <+11>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x10000149d <+13>: popq   %rbp
    0x10000149e <+14>: retq
```

and the

```
let this : Bool? = nil
this != nil
```

to

```
    0x100001490 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x100001491 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100001494 <+4>:  movb   $0x2, 0x3d9595(%rip)      ; gCRAnnotations + 63
    0x10000149b <+11>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x10000149d <+13>: popq   %rbp
    0x10000149e <+14>: retq
```

So the resulted instructions are actually the same and the time to execute them should be pretty close.

Comment: Interesting. And it suggests that the compiler is missing a pretty important optimization opportunity. I'd suggest filing a bug [to the Swift open source project](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: What's the optimization level?

Comment: [Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different), I've updated the response

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322977/whats-the-difference-between-if-nil-optional-and-if-let-optional). They both result in the same underlying assembly instructions. My guess is that they both take such a small amount of time to compile that the time difference you're noticing could be due to other miscellaneous outliers affecting performance.

Comment: This is unlikely because I repeated the test multiple times using multiple scenarios. 
The examples above are just some short code samples.

Comment: Thank you [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704317/jonathan) for mentioning assembly. IDK where my mind was...